# Adding images stored in NSArray to UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

First of all I'm new to programming and I was trying to make an app that has a `UITableView` and displays names that are stored in an array and displays images (icons) besides every name. I have added three images in the bundle and named them `1.jpg`, `2.jpg` and `3.jpg`.

The app works well, but after telling the app that I want to display the images that are stored in the array and run the app the iOS simulator works at first but then I get a green error in my main.m file?

Below is my implementation file:

```
NSMutableArray *myImages;
NSMutableArray *myNames;

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    myNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc ]initWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C", nil];

    for (int imageNumber =1 ; imageNumber <= 3; imageNumber++) {
            myImages= [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i.jpg", imageNumber ]], nil];
      }
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
        return myNames.count;
 }


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     UITableViewCell *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

     cell.textLabel.text = myNames[indexPath.row];

    //everything works fine until i add this line

    cell.imageView.image = myImages [indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: What is a *green* error?

Comment: @MohitPopat i uploaded i photo here https://app.box.com/s/u4biu37l7dsyl8474kur

Comment: did You get your solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image name array should match the length of the names array. Configure them both as literals and try. That is, initialize the arrays like this:

```
NSArray *myNames = @[@"A", @"B", @"C"];
NSArray *myImages = @[@"1.jpg", @"2.jpg", @"3.jpg"];
```

You can also fix it by changing your image loop so that it doesn't create a new NSMutableArray on every iteration:

```
myImages = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int imageNumber =1 ; imageNumber <= 3; imageNumber++) {
    [myImages addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i.jpg", imageNumber]];
}
```

Note that you'll need to create an image using the image name:

```
UIImage *actualImage = [UIImage imageNamed:myImages[indexPath.row]];
```

Comment: Perfect answer. but i'm wondering does the names array length HAVE to match the length of the images array or the app won't work ?

Comment: The only real requirement is that the myImages array is at least as long as whatever you're using in numberOfRowsInSection (so that if the table view asks for the 10th row you don't end up trying to access the 10th element of a 3-element array). You could also create a new class that has properties (eg, imageName, title) to hold the info you're interested in and populate a single array with these objects.

Answer (score 2):

Your array is populated with file names, not images. You need to get the image using the file name. You can do this with `UIImage`'s `imageNamed` method. This will get your images from the app bundle.

Try this: `cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:myImages [indexPath.row]];`

Also, in your `viewDidLoad:`, you are recreating the NSMutableArray every time the loop loops.

Try replacing your viewDidLoad with this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    myNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C", nil];

    for (int imageNumber =1 ; imageNumber <= 3; imageNumber++) 
    {
        [myImages addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.jpg",i]]];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try dis.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    myNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc ]initWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C", nil];
    myImages= [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIImage imagNamed @"1.jpg"],[UIImage imagNamed @"2.jpg"],[UIImage imagNamed @"3.jpg"],];

}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return myNames.count;
}

 -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
return 1; //number of sections in the table. 1 meaning only 1 section.
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    cell.myImageView.image = [myImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     cell.myTextLabel.text = myNames[indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}


;
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so Objective-C is unlike other programming languages in how it handles arrays. In objective-c an array can hold *any* object pointer. So in your line

```
myImages= [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i.jpg", imageNumber ]], nil];
```

you aren't actually creating images and adding them to the array, you're creating the array over and over again. Do this instead

```
[myImages addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.jpg",i]]];
```

Comment: thanks.. and it seems that i have to declare an empty array before the loop `myImages = [NSMutableArray array];`

Answer (score 0):

few comments:

```
    myNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc ]initWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C", nil];
```

can be better written as

```
    NSArray *myNames = @[@"A",@"B",@"C"];
```

Now, your problematic line

```
    cell.imageView.image = myImages [indexPath.row];
```

is a mismatch of types. **cell.imageView.image** is of type UImage*. You cannot assign it with a string.
Maybe this will work:

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:myImages [indexPath.row]];
```

HTH

-Itay

Answer (score 0):

```
[myImages addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.jpg",i]]];
```

Comment: thanks.. and it seems that i have to declare an empty array before the loop `myImages = [NSMutableArray array]`

Answer (score 0):

*Problem in viewDidLoad is you are allocating your array in loop*

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    myNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc ]initWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C", nil];
    myImages= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; 
    for (int imageNumber =1 ; imageNumber <= 3; imageNumber++) {
        [myImages addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i.jpg", imageNumber ]];
    }
}
```

*Problem in cellForrowAtIndexPath is you are setting `NSString` in place of `UIImage`*

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    cell.textLabel.text = myNames[indexPath.row];

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:myNames[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Just replace these two methods And it'll be fine