# My is my setOnClickListener giving me an error?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, button

When I hover over the squiggly red line under "setOnClickListener", there's a pop-up message saying "Cannot resolve symbol setOnClickListener", "@Override" says "Annotations are not allowed here." and the v from "View v" is also giving me an error.  Where did I mess up?

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class EmailReceiptActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_email_receipt);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_options_menu, menu);
    menu.findItem(R.menu.main_options_menu).setIntent(
            new Intent(EmailReceiptActivity.this, LaunchActivity.class));
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    //use the id of the item from main_options_menu
    if (id == R.id.logoff_menu_item) {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        startActivity(item.getIntent());
    }

    return true;
}

Button btn_send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send_receipt_button);
btn_send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    //Use the name of the function you assigned to the xml design of the button
    public void onClick(View v){
        //Use the name of this class, and the name class where you want to be taken when the button is clicked.
        startActivity (new Intent(EmailReceiptActivity.this, SuccessActivity.class));
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move the code to within a method such as `onCreate` in order for the `onClickListener` to be set. You cannot execute code like that outside a function body. Also it may be more useful to declare your `Button` with a more global scope, outside of `onCreate`, so try...

```
public Button btn_send;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_email_receipt);

    btn_send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send_receipt_button);
    btn_send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        //Use the name of the function you assigned to the xml design of the   button
        public void onClick(View v){
            //Use the name of this class, and the name class where you want to be taken when the button is clicked.
            startActivity (new Intent(EmailReceiptActivity.this, SuccessActivity.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: this solved it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

if you want to put your `OnClickListener` outside like that, then it should be like this:

```
OnClickListener sendListener = new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    //Use the name of the function you assigned to the xml design of the button
    public void onClick(View v){
        //Use the name of this class, and the name class where you want to be taken when the button is clicked.
        startActivity (new Intent(EmailReceiptActivity.this, SuccessActivity.class));
    }
};
```

then you set it in an area like `onCreate`

```
Button btn_send;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    btn_send.setOnClickListener(sendListener);
}
```

but ideally, you want to move both your `findViewById` and your `OnClickListener` into an area like `onCreate`

```
Button btn_send;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    btn_send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send_receipt_button);
    btn_send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        //Use the name of the function you assigned to the xml design of the   button
        public void onClick(View v){
            //Use the name of this class, and the name class where you want to be taken when the button is clicked.
            startActivity (new Intent(EmailReceiptActivity.this, SuccessActivity.class));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

private Button send_receipt_button;

```
public class GameOver extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

 @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_email_receipt);
              Button btn_send = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.send_receipt_button);
             btn_send.setOnClickListener(this);

}

  public void onClick (View v){



            switch (v.getId()) {

                case R.id.send_receipt_button:
                     startActivity (new Intent(EmailReceiptActivity.this, SuccessActivity.class));


                    break;
}
}
```

Comment: This answer looks like original content, but you should know that I googled a little bit of the answer you gave here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39429490/pass-image-array-from-view-did-load-to-tableview-cell?noredirect=1#comment66182594_39429490)  Deleting it was the right thing to do, since it was copied without attribution from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25081954/294949.  That's considered plagiarism, is very much frowned upon here, and is easy (as you can see) to discover.

Comment: This is my original code that i´m using on my apps. And show answer´s that exist is to help and dont plagiarism, plagiarism is not things that are posting in one blog or service wiki. Think to answer

Comment: I'm sure your motive is to help others, and that's appreciated. The right way to show somebody another person's answer is to *link* to it.  If it makes more sense for the reader to copy part of it, then cite the source.

Comment: Its make sense to only show the best answer for the user. Only want to help.